# LinkedIn - Getting Access Token Error

Tags: rest, linkedin-api, postman, access-token

All,

I am facing authentication issues that I see others have also complained about. Following [official documentation](https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/oauth2) I was able to get the client id and client secret but when I try to get Access Token I am getting this error:

{
    "error": "invalid_request",
    "error_description": "A required parameter \"client_id\" is missing"
}

I am using POSTMAN to get the access token. After getting the Access Token I intend to work with LinkedIn REST APIs with other software that could consume REST. I am not sure why I am getting this error, I wonder is it not possible to get the token from POSTMAN and have to use Python script?

Also, redirect_uri in step 2 is not a functional callback uri, it's an imaginary URL. Do I need a valid callback URL?

Answer (score 4):

Since you are getting this error

```
{ 
  "error": "invalid_request", 
  "error_description": "A required parameter \"client_id\" is missing" 
}
```

This is giving a hint that you might need to change the `Client Authentication` drop-down value to `Send client credential in body` instead of `Send as Basic auth header`

This is because when `client_id` and `client_secret` are sent in the header, they are combined and converted to base64

```
Authorization: Basic base64($client_id + ':' $client_secret)
```

So, no separate `client_id` is ever sent. But if you choose to send the credentials in body then they are sent separately.

For more info, you can refer the offical RFC here https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-2.3.1

[image]

Comment: Thanks Harry - that approach did not work well, if I use the "generate new access token" from the Postman I get redirected to the redirect uri, I am not getting any access code. If I do a POST and supply all parameters I still get the aforementioned error.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue by adding keys/values in the Params.

[image]